# how to disable selection on inset of UITableCell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created fake space between UITableViewCell by insetting the content.

```
contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0))
```

However, the UITableCell still accepts selection events based when selecting between the cells because even the non-inset 8 pixels is still contained within the UITableViewCell.

Is there a proper way of doing this so that selection does not occur?

I feel like this is a hack, so I am wondering what the more normal way of doing things is. I kind of would expect a property on the tableview itself to set the inset from interface builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always override `hitTest` or `pointInside` in your tableView cell. You have mentioned that you are setting the `contentView.frame` assuming that its updating fine, you can simply use one of the below implementation

```
class SOTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if contentView.frame.contains(point) {
            return super.hitTest(point, with: event) /*return self*/
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Or

```
class SOTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return contentView.frame.contains(point)
    }
}
```

Comment: I still feel like this shouldn't be necessary though. All these myriad settings for uitableview,'s, but nothing that just lets you inset the cell including its hit testing?

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve it, typically you can add a view as subview to contentView with padding all around and apply clear color to cell's background color there by creating a illusion of separation and adding tap gesture to subview and not implementing `didSelectRow` will do the trick, but I guess cleanest way to achieve it is with `inset` and overriding `hitTest` or `pointInside` isnt a bad approach, they are public APIs but yeah I understand your point, but havent come across any such API myself :|

Comment: ok thank you for your thoughts and help. I probably could have thought of using hitTesting myself too, but I thought maybe it wasn't necessary. For one thing, I have the weird situation where another tableview in my project appears to be working without it, but I'm not sure how it's working. I will try looking at that version tomorrow too just to see why I didn't have to override hit testing before

Comment: @james-joshua-street: I have updated my answer, I did not realize that you are already setting `contentView.frame = ` re-evaluating this frame in either `hitTest` or `point(inside ` is unnecessary, and you can directly use `contentView.frame.contains(point)` I have updated the answer to reflect the same :)

Comment: after testing both, it seems overriding hit test breaks my checkboxes inside the UITableViewCell, so I recommend overriding point as that seems to keep everything inside working properly

Comment: @james-joshua-street: Technically both `hitTest` and `point(inside` both should work if checkbox is added as a subView to your `contentView`. The problem might be occurring because of the fact that in `hitTest` am returning simply `self` I did it to keep the answer simple and I wasnt aware of complexity of your cell, you can  `return super.hitTest(point, with: event)` rather than simply returning `self` that should ensure that touch gets propagated through view chain/hierarchy, I am updating my answer, please check and confirm if that works for you :)

Comment: @james-joshua-street: I have updated `hitTest` with `return super.hitTest(point, with: event)` as I mentioned this should propagate the touch to other views in view hierarchy, lemme know if that solves your problem, for a simple cell with no other components that requires explicit touch self will work ( i experimented with default cell before answering) but it makes sense to call `super.hitTest` hence updated the answer